# Set up Right Click Run script in context menu, (pull the file path of file that's being clicked as a variable)

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, contextmenu

How can I configure my PC so that I can right click a file and select "Send to FTP"

As in editing the registry to edit the context menu, so that it knows what's been Right clicked
and adds it in the path, something like in the registry command

```
(
copy "%L" \\COMPFTP\inetpub\ftproot\
)
```

Where "%L" is the path of the selected Icon/exe/object
Just like

```
copy "C:\Backup" \\COMPFTP\inetpub\ftproot\
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ended up creating a Shortcut under
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
and the target of the shortcut was \COMPFTP\inetpub\ftproot\ 
after I shared the initial ftproot directory.

I can now Right click Send to FTPServer